# I need help creating an html data table

Tags: html, datatables

I've been trying to create an HTML form on my own for a few months with no luck. I'm trying to do something like the form on this site, http://whatimplantisthat.com/ I'm not sure what this style of form is called. I'm assuming that it is a data table with images, but i haven't seen anything online like this form. Please Help Thanks

Comment: I guess you'd start with some introductory tutorials on HTML and CSS.  You can also look at the source code for the page you linked and see how they're doing it.

Comment: Look up `<table>`.

Comment: Hi David. Ive looked up the code and have been able to grab it from the site. I even have the pictures loaded on a server but i can't fully recreate how they load depending on the choice of the dropdown. I'm not sure where the database is or how to recreate that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to the table of images in the middle of the page? This uses the HTML  tag, and associated tags. You can find information on this here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp.

I was able to figure out what the markup looks like by using Chrome developer tools, an invaluable resource for anyone doing any kind of web design or development. Chrome dev tools info can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools. I believe the other browsers all have similar tools.

Comment: Hi dudedmontag, I've looked up all of that. I think my main problem is recreating the database.....I'm not sure where it's located or how to change the source of everything into the new location.

Comment: I have this page so far on this website that i created.....www.implantfinders.com......i'm trying to paginate it.....I think thats the first place, but if im not mistaken i have to create a databse through myphpadmin but i just don't know.....does anyone know of a coder who i could hire?

Comment: I think there's a little confusion around the word "table" here. There is the table that is an HTML tag, and is used purely for positioning elements on a web page. Then there is a table in a database, a concept that describes the attributes of a record. I thought at first you wanted to know how to markup the former, but it sounds like you want the latter.

To do that, you would probably want to use a framework like Ruby on Rails, that has a way for you to interface with a database.